# AS3 Load External SWF with googleMap component inside, why compiler raise error to null object pointer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-maps

I'll try to be short, because I guess this problem is related to the use of the googleMap component inside Flash IDE.

I have a swf file compiled with a googleMap component inside, and by itself it works great.

Problem raises whe i try to load it into another Swf file, adding it to as a child of  a Movieclip.

If, with the same loader code i try to load another simple swf, I have no problems.
So I'm pretty sure the problem is related to this particular swf that uses googleMap component.

As my first Idea to solve this I tryed to add the googleMapsLibraryComponent, draggin it inside the MovieClip was supposed to load this external ggMap swf file. But nothing still have
a message Error #1009 tryin to access a property or method of a null object, inside the constructor of the base class of the child external swf.

Sub question #2:
Also, how is it possible to debug such a situation? Since I'm dealing with a compiled swf? no chance but to debug them separately?

many thanks in advance...

Comment: It's been so long since i used the google maps in Flash. things i'd double check: Same AS version in both FLAs, both FLAs in same directory, that's really all i can think of, would you copy/paste some code to look at?

For sub q 2: have you tried debug mode in flash? You know how cmd (control)+ enter previews the swf? well shift + cmd (cntrl) + enter will enter debug mode, it may help :)

Comment: They are both same version AS3. I have both fla sources n' compiled same way. yes i'll give a try with debug mode also, even if it is so slow...:/

Comment: Sounds like an initialization error. Try moving all code out of the constructor and into a public init method which you then call from the parent swf once the child swf is completely loaded.

Comment: I know with the google maps flash api you have to wait for a map ready event to be fired before you can make calls on the map object otherwise you'll receive errors, I would take Will's advice as a test, make a button you click to make the call on the google map instead of calling it directly (even if this is in the embedded swf) might be a difference in load time when it's pulled into an already executing swf.